# I have a problem dynamic memory allocation

Tags: arrays, c, memory-management

```
int szar(t_obraz obr)
{
    int x = 0, i, j;
    int **wsp;
    wsp = (int **)malloc(obr.wymy * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < obr.wymy; i++)
    {
        wsp[i] = (int *)malloc(obr.wymx * sizeof(int));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < obr.wymy; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < 3 * obr.wymx; j += 3)
        {
            wsp[i][x] = (obr.obraz[i][j - 1] + obr.obraz[i][j] + obr.obraz[i][j + 1]) / 3;
            x++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < obr.wymy; i++)
    {
        obr.obraz[i] = (int *)realloc(obr.obraz[i], obr.wymx * sizeof(int));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < obr.wymy; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < obr.wymx; j++)
        {
            obr.obraz[i][j] = wsp[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < obr.wymy; i++)
    {
        free(wsp[i]);
    }
    free(wsp);
}
```

I have segmentation fault(core dumped), when try to compile that. I have array obraz[wymy][3*wymx] in structure t_obraz.

Comment: You also have a problem with indentation, (lack of).

Comment: You should include type declarations, especially for structs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reset your `x` in the outer Loop

```
for (i=0;i<obr.wymy;i++) {
    x = 0; // here
    for (j=1;j<3*obr.wymx;j+=3) {
        wsp[i][x]=(obr.obraz[i][j-1]+obr.obraz[i][j]+obr.obraz[i][j+1])/3;
        x++;
    }
}
```